# Issue when parsing array[1][2] using Megaparsec

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

I was following [Megaparsec](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/issues/64) [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-4.4.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec-Expr.html#v:makeExprParser) to parse multidimensional array.

```
opSubscript = Postfix $ foldr1 (.) <$> some singleIndex

singleIndex = do
  index < brackets expr
  return $ \l -> ArrayIndex l index
```

`array[1][2]` is expected to be parsed as

```
ArrayIndex (ArrayIndex (Var "array") 1)) 2
```

However, it was

```
ArrayIndex (ArrayIndex (Var "array") 2)) 1
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`some singleIndex` has parsed a list containing two functions, `[f, g]`, where

```
f = \l -> ArrayIndex l 1
g = \l -> ArrayIndex l 2
```

And then composed them with `foldr1`. And since

```
foldr1 f [x, y] = x `f` y
```

your resulting function is `f . g`. Naturally this applies `g` first, yielding `ArrayIndex (Var "array") 2`, and then applies `f` next, yielding `ArrayIndex (ArrayIndex (Var "array") 2) 1`.

So your parsing is fine, but you are composing the results wrong. You want a different associativity, or order or something.

Comment: `opSubscript = Postfix $ foldr1 (flip (.)) <$> some singleIndex` fixed it.